# In ConTeXt, how to hide floats captions, but still list them via the completelistofxxx?

Tags: floats, captions, context

My goal is to **display floats** (a custom type, but I don't think this is relevant) **without caption, but to still be able to list them all** at the end of my document via their title.

I'm using the following code (using `figure` instead of my custom float):

```
\starttext

    \startbodymater

        \startplacefigure[location=none,title="title1"]
            ...
        \stopplacefigure

        \startplacefigure[location=none,title="title2"]
            ...
        \stopplacefigure

    \endbodymater

    \startbackmatter
        \completelistoffigures
    \stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

The floats are indeed displayed without caption, but the list in the back matter is empty.

Conversely, if I remove the `location=none` option, the list is correctly filled, but each float has a caption.

Is there a way to both hide the captions and list all the floats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your code is not valid ConTeXt.  Second, it does not represent a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which makes it a little harder to answer.  Especially the definition of `myfloat` was missing so I just made something up.

To display a float but hide its caption, we can use `\setupfloatcaption` with the option `location=none`.  This is similar but not equivalent to `\startplacefloat` with `location=none`, because in `\startplacefloat` all other options affecting the caption will then be ignored.  To still have the title in the list, use `list=...` in the `\startplacefloat` command.

To be honest, I don't see the point of listing floats when there is no way to identify them.  I mean, when I look in the table and think “I want to see the float with title1”, how am I supposed to find it?  What if there are multiple floats on one page?  Do I count which one is which?  Please, do your readers a favour and display the caption.

```
\definefloat
  [myfloat]
  [myfloats]

\setupfloatcaption
  [myfloat]
  [location=none]

\starttext

\startbodymatter

  \startplacemyfloat[list="title1"]
    ...
  \stopplacemyfloat

  \startplacemyfloat[list="title2"]
    ...
  \stopplacemyfloat

\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter
  \completelistofmyfloats
\stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I've edited the code to use `figure` instead of `myfloat`. As for your remark regarding the absence of caption, the thing is the new floats I'm creating are examples, i.e. text in a frame. I insert the caption content as a "title" on the first line of the framed text, therefore I do not want it to appear a second time outside of the frame. Maybe there is a way to directly put the caption inside the frame but, since I did not know whether that was possible, I opted for the other option, i.e. removing the caption and "manually" inserting the title inside the frame.

Comment: @Silverspur So does my code solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it perfectly does.